# Visual Studio Code, C# support on Windows

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-code

I want to try out a new editor from Microsoft - Visual Studio Code.
I want to implement a simple app (like Hello, World) and be able to debug it. But after a lot of googling and trying, I didn't manage to do that. Is that possible? I have Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 installed.

What I've tried to do:

1) Uncomment the following in the tasks.json file:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "msbuild",
"args": [
    // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
],
"taskSelector": "/t:",
"showOutput": "silent",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
        "showOutput": "silent",
        // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings
        // and infos in the output.
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

But compiling (ctrl-shift-b) fails with the error: "Failed to launch external program msbuild .
spawn msbuild ENOENT"

2) Read this article: http://michaelcrump.net/creating-and-debugging-console-apps-with-vscode/, but I don't have any project.json file, also "`dnx . run`" fails with the error "*System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project*"

Is there a simple way to run simple C# app in VS Code? I'm wondering why it's so complicated. Probably, I'm missing something, any ideas are welcome.

Update 1: Adding msbuild to path helps

Comment: VS Code still has limited features. It will be much easier to run your simple C# app in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I also just found VSC and it would be a great quick alternative to VS for small changes, but i get the same error.

Comment: @svanelten, unfortunately, no. But I used old version of VS Code, which version do you have?

Comment: The current version, 0.5.0. I'm really looking forward to it maturing to replace sublime Text for me.

Comment: @pfedotovsky  Hi, it actually works now - i added msbuild to my user `PATH`, restarted and it works. Previously i had only added it to the system path.

Comment: @svanelten, Great! I'll try it :)

Comment: @svanelten, adding msbuild to PATH helped, though I still have issues with my Xamarin.Forms project. There a lot of errors related to OmniSharp

Comment: See this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694925/create-a-visual-studio-code-c-sharp-console-application

Answer (score 7):

> The C# support in VS Code is optimized for cross platform .NET
>   development (DNX) (see working with ASP.NET 5 and VS Code for another
>   relevant article. Our focus with VS Code is to be a great editor for
>   cross platfrom C# development - for instance many Unity developers
>   have been enjoying using VS Code in place of Mono Develop.
>
> We support debugging of C# apps cross platfrom via Mono (see Mono
>   Debugging).
>
> Due to this focus many standard C# project types are not recognised by
>   VS Code. An example of a non-supported project type is an ASP .NET MVC
>   Application. In these cases if you simply want to have a lightweight
>   tool to edit a file - VS Code has you covered. If you want the best
>   possible experience for those projects, and development on Windows in
>   general we recomend you use Visual Studio Community.

from: [code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp)

---

**Update, June 2017:**

C# is supported in Visual Studio Code using Microsoft's VS Code C# extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

This can be installed by searching for 'C#' in Extensions: Install Extension. Alternatively, opening a `.cs` file should prompt to install extension.

This extension supports debugging of C# applications running on ***.NET Core*** or **Mono**, however *does not* support debugging applications running on the *Desktop .NET Framework* - [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is still recommended for full .NET project support.

For more info regarding VS Code's C# support, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

For the marketplace page for the VS Code C# extension, see https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp

Answer (score 6):

You can set up `msbuild` for building full `.NET` apps just fine, note you either have to have `msbuild` on path or provide full path to it in `command` property. This is what example build task (bound to `ctrl + shift + b`) looks like:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "MSBuild.exe",
    "args": [
        // $msCompile requires GenerateFullPaths=true, rest is optional. I set it to build Debug/Any CPU and use parallel project build
        "${workspaceRoot}/src/ExampleSolution.sln",
        "/p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=Any CPU;GenerateFullPaths=true",
        "/m"
    ],
    "taskSelector": "/t:",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Rebuild",
            // Required if you want "Rebuild", not build as your target and still use ctrl + shift + b hotkey
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "silent",
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPD**: If you want to set up both building and unit test running, you can use something like this (uses `nunit` console runner and `cmd` as a task to hack around `vscode` limitation of supporting only single task):

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "cmd",
    "args": [
        "/c"
    ],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "taskName": "MSBuild.exe",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/src/Example.sln",
                "/t:Rebuild",
                "/p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=Any CPU;GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/m"
            ],
            "showOutput": "always",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "nunit3-console.exe",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/src/Example.sln"
            ],
            "showOutput": "always"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Changed direct path to msbuild fixed it:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "windows": {
        "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
    },
   // "command": "msbuild",
    "args": [
        // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
        "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
    ],
    "taskSelector": "/t:",
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "silent",
            // Use the standard MS compiler pattern to detect errors, warnings and infos
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```